# Finding value of x using provided graph

Tags: functions

I have a question that showed up in my revision, and hoped someone could help me.

Here it goes:

Shown below are the graphs of $y = f (x)$ and $y = g (x)$ , If $$(f \circ g)(x) = 3$$, find all the possible values of $x$.

[image]

Comment: Start by finding out where $f(t) = 3$, and work backwards. Can you share what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with?

Comment: Well i attempted to find both f(x) and g(x) however then if I made the (fog)(x) I seemed to make it unnecessarily difficult. I was just wondering if there is an easier and neater method to attain the result.

Comment: Oh and I don't understand what u mean user61527

Comment: @Pauly See my answer. Hope you understand it.

Comment: Sorry I am still unsure do mind going in depth

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $f(t)=3$ when $t=0,3$. Hence, we'd expect $g(x)=0$ or $g(x)=3$. The values of $x$ shouldn't be hard to figure out.